# Passing two parameters from combobox onChange event

Tags: grails, combobox, onchange

I have the following code:

```
<g:select name="availableUser.id" from="${availableUsers}"
                  noSelection="['': message(code: 'global.noSelection')]"
                  optionKey="id" value="${name}"
                  onchange="${remoteFunction(
                          controller: 'report',
                          action: 'getAvailableUsers',
                          params: [report: reportInstance.id, user: this.value],
                          update: 'userSelection'
                  )}">
```

In remote function getAvailableUser I can access passed parameter named report but the other one(user) is constantly returning null even though combobox is properly rendered. Like this:

```
...

<option value="21">John Smith</option> 

...
```

I'm trying to get the value of selected item. In this instance, 21.

Comment: I succeeded like this: params: "'user.id=' + this.value + '&&report=' + '${reportInstance.id}'"

Comment: But I'm still wondering what was the problem with the original idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `remoteFunction` in turn writes a JS function which fires an AJAX request based on the corressponding library used (`JQuery`, `DOJO` etc). `params` attribute is requried to me mentioned in the native format based on the AJAX library you use for your project.

Mark the difference when different libraries are used

JQuery:
`'\'user.id=\' + this.value + \'&report=\' + ${reportInstance.id}'`

DOJO: [Use of Semi colons for Key-value pair]

`'\'user.id:\' + this.value + \', report:\' + ${reportInstance.id}'`