# Grails: Populate dropdown list when another dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, drop-down-menu

I have a situation where I need to populate a drop down list on my gsp once a choice is made in another drop down list. I am not sure how to go about this. I have the parent dropdown list populated via a model map right before the gsp is rendered.

I can easily provide model info to a gsp from my controller right before the gsp is rendered but I have trouble creating and passing a model to a gsp on the fly i.e. once the gsp is already rendered how to do it? Should I send it as ajax or how? I just can't seem to see it. Im not looking for an exact code answer as much as conceptual advice.

The first step I am doing is to try to invoke a function in the controller when the parent drop down list on the gsp is used to choose a value:

```
<g:select name = "seleInst" from = "${instlist}" style = "border-radius: 5px" onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'updateUserlist(this.value)', controller: 'admin')}"></g:select>
```

The problem I face here is how to pass to the controller method the argument(value selected in parent dropdown list). I just put it in parenthesis above to help me think. This is probably not the correct syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue so I am also wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to populate the second list via ajax. Using jQuery this is pretty simple.

1. Attach an on("change") event listener to the first select list.
2. Make an ajax call to get a JSON response from your controller, passing the selected value.
3. Use the JSON response from the controller to populate the second list with option elements.

I can provide detailed code examples of each if that is really needed, but you stated you just wanted conceptual advice so let's start with that.

**updated**

Seeing that you are using the `remoteFunction` (which is going away in future versions of Grails I might mention) you are going to struggle a bit getting your parameters in there correctly.

However, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194621/passing-two-parameters-from-combobox-onchange-event) it can be done. If you are using a 2.x version of Grails then your provider will be jQuery. I have always stayed away from the `remoteFunction` tag personally and written my own jQuery.

Comment: thanks so much for the advice. Greatly appreciate it. I've got a function attached to parent dropdown list which will invoke a method in the controller onchange, but it also needs to let that method know what the value selected in this parent list is. That value will determine what the child list gets populated with. Is there a way to pass this 'argument' from the gsp back to the controller? i.e. the value being what was selected in the parent list.

Comment: Depends on how you have attached this function on the client-side. Post a snippet of that in your question and I can demonstrate that in the answer. Typically it's going to be $("#idOfTheParent").val() if you are using jQuery.